# Can there be robot upvotes?

Tags: support, votes

During each of the last five days, some of my answers - most being
quite old - were upvoted within a short lapse of time. More precisely:
5, 3, 3, 3, 3 answers were upvoted within a few minutes for each
day.

It is always pleasant to have upvotes, and some of these answers could
be considered as underrated e.g, [this
one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/199343/10479) which was upvoted
for the first time. Yet this seems quite strange. May I fear to have
met a robot fan?

Comment: Most likely, no. Somebody liked one of your posts, looked around, and upvoted it and some others. But checks are run. Beyond some threshold, excessive upvoting (and perhaps more importantly downvoting) will be reversed as probably personal rather than on substance.

Comment: Don't worry about it. In addition to the automatic reversal mechanism @NickCox mentions, there are reports that alert moderators to suspicious behaviour.

Comment: Thank you @Nick Cox and Scortchi. Sorry not to have found the similar question.

Comment: No problem, @Yves, similar questions aren't always obvious.